# Emphasize diffrence in a chart

Tags: interface-design, visualization

I need to present a chart (not really specified more than that right now) that will consist of two *almost* equal parts (ie ~50% each). However, a pie-chart would almost always look about the same, given that the diffrance remain small.

I need to find a way that illustrate and emphasize the larger of the two parts. A pie chart with 51%/49%-parts looks to dull.

One solution is to display a bar chart with a broken axis, but is there any other way? Accuracy (to the underlaying data) is not a great importance.

Comment: I am not sure this can be answered without knowing what you're really trying to show. Can you provide background, carefully disguised if necessary? What's important about the larger of the two parts? Why can't you concentrate on the 2% difference?

Comment: Well, I guess what I am trying to achieve is a way to emphasize the 2%-diffrence, in my mind that meant emphasize the larger of two parts... What would be a good way to illustrate the diffrence?

Comment: It all depends. Can you compare the 2% with other measures? Has it been less than 1% for five years? Is it greater than company X's 1.4% and company Y's 1.8%? Try not to directly compare the 49 and 51.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a pie chart and then separate the two pieces. Have them floating next to each other and throw on some effects (drop shadow, 3D). Use vivid, contrasting colors for the slices (blue and orange, purple and yellow). Put the percentages in big numbers.

Comment: Good idea, perhaps even enlargeing the greater pie-piece...

Comment: -1. None of this except showing the numbers will emphasise the larger piece. In fact, just choosing a pie chart is a sure way to hide differences between two similar quantities.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to misrepresent, rather than present, you can just do what the big boys do and start the scale at or slightly below the lower of the two values, with the second value plus some small amount for the max value. Don't label the scale with any values and you are good to go.

Another way is to improperly use a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Nearly any technique can be used to 'misrepresent' as much as 'represent' from the standpoint of communicating a message to an audience. A scientist may not approve, but in terms of general communication, it's not necessarily good/bad right/wrong.

Comment: Perhaps I have triggered some knee-jerk reaction in you, but the OP says "accuracy to the underlying data is not important." This is nearly the definition of misrepresentation.

Comment: well, perhaps we're arguing semantics. I guess what I was getting at is as graphic designers, our job is to communicate a particular message. Like it or not, we're a cog in the consumer driven market and we need to not always screen 'misrepresentation' when it's sometimes more 'massaging the message'. About the only way to communicate pure accurate data is a list of numbers. But even in that state, there are visual elements that can communicate meaning that some may construe as misrepresentation.

Comment: Maybe another way to put it: As soon as we begin visualizing the data, we're manipulating the message.

Comment: Yeah, it is semantics. I think it is clear that conveying any kind of quantifiable data without regard to the accuracy of the representation is a misrepresentation and feelings of guilt are optional.

Comment: I'd state: I think it is clear that conveying any kind of quantifiable data VISUALLY can be considered a misrepresentation in terms of data accuracy. There's many degrees of that, of course, some bad, some innocuous.

Comment: Example. Let's say you need a product. Company X and company Y both sell it. X's product is rated at a quality of 51%. Y's is rated at 49%. They cost the same amount. Now a chart with an axis going from 0 to 100 would likely show the two as pretty much being equal and the CEO may simply flip a coin to make the decision. But if the axis is 45-55, it may become quite clear to the CEO that one is obviously more highly rated, even if marginally...

Comment: ...One can certainly call that misrepresentation of the data, but I call that a proper presentation of the particular message that is trying to be communicated (one of the products is better than the other).

Comment: And if the axis is not properly labeled, then the CEO thinks X is 20-30% better. In addition in reality the error between 49 and 51 % is larger than the difference between the numbers. This is a misrepresentation.

Comment: Well, we're not going to agree. ;) Good discussion, though.

Comment: @ horatio - take a look at share price charts for an example of where cutting off the bottom is not wrong (you're interested in change, not absolutes).

Comment: @e100: This is an old thread, but I will once again point out a few crucial excerpts from the conversation: "Accuracy (to the underlaying data) is not a great importance"; "improper use of [scales]". The whole point of the question was misrepresentation, and for some reason you and da01 think that speaking about misrepresentation implicates graphs as a class.